# Use PowerShell to strip data

Tags: powershell

I have a file that contains data such as:

`ABC|LT293012|293012
ABC|LT9281749|9281749
ABC|LT12345|12345`

I want to create a comma-delimited string out of it that looks like:

```
LT293012,LT9281749,LT12345
```

In other words, everything (including) the first | and everything (including) after the second | need to be stripped.

I've used:

```
$list=(Get-Content $file).replace("ABC`|", "") -join ","
```

but that does not strip the second | and data

Although 'ABC' should always be a static value if it is easier to just leave anything surrounded by the pipe character, that would be fine. There will ALWAYS be three elements to the value.

I suppose I could read in the file using ConvertFrom-CSV, add headers, and pipe that into a select, pulling only the middle element, but there is probably an easier way of doing it.

**EDIT**: I forgot a key piece. Each element needs to be enclosed in a single quote so that the final output is `'LT293012','LT9281749','LT12345'`

Comment: That works great. One line, easy to understand. I was trying to do something similar but forgot to use -expand. Still learning :-)

Comment: Dang it, I forgot a key piece. Each elsement needs to be enclosed in a single quote so that the final output is 'LT293012','LT9281749','LT12345'

Comment: [Posted an answer instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40748186/712649)

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
$data=get-content .\yourdatafile.txt|ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "|" -Header "a","b","c"
$data.b  -join ","
```

gives:

LT293012,LT9281749,LT12345

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple, just use the `-Replace` operator instead of the `.Replace()` method. The operator works with RegEx, so you can do:

```
$list=((Get-Content $file)-replace "^.+?\|(.+?)\|.*$", '''$1''') -join ','
```

It should be pretty quick since you are just reading it in as text and not full blown objects.

Since my RegEx is evidently confusing, here's a [link to RegEx101.com](https://www.regex101.com/r/1mlXYE/1) that explains it.

Comment: yeah, fairly simple, anyone can understand this bullcrap easily `"^.+?\|(.+?)\|.*$"`

Comment: Anybody familiar with Regular Expressions can understand it, and if the OP has questions it's easily enough explained.

Comment: RegEx is not _bullcrap_, it's powerful. And you can even use it yourself :).

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Well, I'm familiar with it, but those kinds of patterns are just unreadable ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I suppose I could read in the file using ConvertFrom-CSV, add headers, and pipe that into a select, pulling only the middle element, but there is probably an easier way of doing it.

I would contend that using the `*-Csv` cmdlets *is* the easy way to do it.

Since you need to reed it from a file, use `Import-Csv`:

```
$list = (Import-Csv $file -Delimiter '|' -Header 1,2,3 |Select -Expand 2 |ForEach {"'$_'"})
($list -join ',') |Out-File result.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

just do it

```
(ipcsv "c:\temp\exludevalue.txt" -d "|" -Header c1, c2).c2  -join ","
```